# Github - clone repo then push to my fork

Tags: git, github

I am new to git so please go easy on me :)

I have cloned a repo from Github and made some local changes. But now I would like to fork the original repo and push local changes to the forked repo.

Is this possible?

Comment: I would also advise you to have a good look at this [really good resource](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project#Forked-Public-Project). It includes the answer to your question and much more. I find the examples of different workflows one may use really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fork the repo (by clicking `Fork` on GitHub) and add a new remote:

```
git remote add hub YOUR-CLONE-URL
```

Then simply add, commit, push (`git push -u hub master`).

If you can provide a link to your fork I can give you the exact commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that won't  be necessary :)

Comment: Let me know if that works! You could also remove the other remote: `git remote rm origin` and add your clone url as that: `git remote add origin YOUR-CLONE-URL`. Then the push would be: `git push -u origin master`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can definitely do that! After forking the repository that you wish to fork, then either add a new remote url or change the remote origin in your locally cloned repository.

To add a new remote url, use:

```
git remote add <new_name> <the_new_URL>
```

To change the remote origin, you may edit the `.git/config` file in your local repository directory. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are ok, but I would also advise you to have a good look at this [really good resource](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project#Forked-Public-Project).

It includes the answer to your question and much more. I find the examples of different workflows one may use really helpful.

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment.